# Mixing dynamic objects with structural typing in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to do this? (I'm using scala 2.10) To call a method that requires that the object has a function named "fullName", but the object being built with the Dynamic trait. The compiler complains, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

I don't need this for any job, I'm just learning the language.

```
import scala.language.dynamics

object Main extends App {

    class MyStatic {

        private var privateName = ""
        var lastName = ""

        def name_= (n: String) {
            privateName = n
        }

        def name = s"***$privateName***"

        def fullName = s"$name $lastName"

    }

    class MyDynamic extends scala.Dynamic {

        val map = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

        def selectDynamic(key: String): String = map(key)

        def updateDynamic(key: String)(value: String) {
            map += key -> value
        }

        def applyDynamic(key: String)(value: Any*) = key match {
            case "fullName" => {
                val name = map("name")
                val lastName = map("lastName")
                s"$name $lastName"
            }
        }

    }

    def showFullName(o: { def fullName: String }) = s"My full name is $o.fullName"

    println("Starting App...")

    val s = new MyStatic
    s.name = "Peter"
    s.lastName = "Parker"
    println(showFullName(s))

    val d = new MyDynamic
    d.name = "Bruce"
    d.lastName = "Wayne"
    println(showFullName(d))

}
```

Comment: Could you add the compilation error to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structural type `{ def fullName: String }` basically means "any type with a no-arg method named `fullName` returning a `String`.
`MyDynamic` has no such method, and thus does not comply with this structural type. The fact that `MyDynamic` extends `scala.Dynamic` is irreleveant: it means that for any instance of it, you can perform what *looks* like a call to `fullName`, but it does not mean that `MyDynamic` (as a type) has any such member.

So the short answer is **no**, you cannot mix dynamic objects with structural typing like that.

For completeness, I must add that it *could* be made to work as you expected, but it would require a special provision from the compiler (namely, the compiler could consider than any type extending `scala.Dynamic` -- and implementing the required lookup methods -- is compatible with any structural typing, and implement the call not via reflection as is normally done, but by calling the corresponding lookup method).

Comment: Ok, so the thing is that Dynamic is not actually dynamic (reflection / invokeDynamic / resolution at runtime), but at compile time the compiler "replaces" the calls to the methods to calls to applyDynamic / selectDynamic. OTOH structural typing does use reflection. It would need some way to intercept the runtime call, or like you said, to stop using reflection and use more compile-time magic. I wonder how it will inter-operate with dynamic languages such as Groovy or Jython.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to glue together two completely different things. While structural typing is also sometimes compared to 'duck-typing', its feature is exactly the use of *static type* information (even if on the use site the byte code will call reflection). Per definition, your dynamic type does not have such static type information. So you will never be able to convince the Scala compiler that your dynamic type has a method that can be statically verified to exist.

The only workaround would be to allow *any* type in `showFullName` and use reflection to call `fullName` (again, I'm not sure if this plays out with a dynamic object).

---

On the other hand, Scala will let you do anything with dynamic types, handing the responsibility over to you:

```
def showFullName(o: Dynamic) = s"My full name is $o.fullName"

println(showFullName(d))
```

Comment: BTW: your test against `"fullName"` should not be in `applyDynamic` (that would only allow to make an assignment, but not retrieve it). You should add that check to `selectDynamic`, then my last example works.

Comment: It's applyDynamic because I'm trying to emulate a method, instead of a field (if I understood correctly).